# Trouble getting required output in C++

Tags: c++, loops, conditional-statements

We received a question in an assignment. I had trouble interpreting it so I rewrote it in c++, with the same conditions. However, I cannot seem to get the correct outputs listed in the question. Can anybody advise me on how to proceed?

This is a snip of the Question.
[image: 1]

Here is my code:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
        int n; //AreWeThereYet
        string a;
        a="Yes we have arrived";
        string b;
        b="We just left";
        string c;
        c="That was annoying";
        string d;
        d="Almost";
        int i;
    
        cout << "enter n" << endl;
        cin >> n;
    
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
            //here starts the calc
            if(n==0){
                cout << a << endl;
                return 0;
            }
            if(n>5){
                cout << b << endl;
                n=(n-1);
            }else if(n>1){
                n=(n-2);
                cout << c << endl;
            }else{
                cout << d << endl;
                n=(n-1);
            }
        }
    }
```

The loop seems to be unable to output the first and last question.

I figured that if I replicate the question, I could go by trial and error to attain the answers I needed.
Below I've attached an image of my output. I expected the entry of '1' to output "Almost" followed by "Yes we have arrived".

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws2Kz.png)

Comment: In the question a loop isn't being used, a function is being recursively called.

Comment: all necessary information should be directly in the question. Please include expected and actual output and input

Comment: the image you linked asks to determine `n` for a given output of the shown code. Your code seems to try to replicate the code in the image instead of trying to replicate its input for given output

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I am brand new to stack overflow and Computer Science as well. Im not yet sure how to set out code to replicate the input. I will try add an image to show my output in the terminal. Would you be able to possibly assist me over discord? If not then no problem.

Comment: sorry, no. Just make sure all information is in the question. If you want to first replicate the code in the assignment, before you write the code that does the reverse, thats fine, but you should explain in the question what your code is supposed to do and what it does instead. A simple way to do that is to include input, expected and actual output in the question

Comment: This can be answered without writing any code. Writing code won't hurt, to be sure. But being able to reason through it is the idea, and the better practice.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)` what exactly corresponds to `i<=n` in the original question?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. A friend suggested I should use it to create a loop so that the output text continues to display and the program doesn't end after the first line.

Comment: Also note that in some branches of the original question the recursive call ia before the print and in other branches it's the other way around. The order is essential. You cannot reproduce all of it with a simple loop.

Comment: ”A friend suggested” is not exactly an answer to my question. I recommend you try answering it. An answer would be something like "it corresponds to the expression ABC on line XYZ" of the original question".

Comment: I was told that the loop would continue until "i" reached the value of "n". I am still unsure as to how this applies. My apologies if I am frustrating you. I am a month into my course and I am still very unfamiliar with terms and the understanding. If you wish to move on and answer some other questions feel free. You have already helped me immensely.

Comment: I can understand what `i<=n` *means*, this is not necessary to explain. What I'm asking is where this condition *comes from*. Why did you write `i<=n`? Why not `i<n`? Why not `i<n-1`? Why not `i<=n+1`? Why not `2*i<=3*n`? There is nothing remotely similar to any of these expressions anywhere in the question, and yet you somehow decided to select one of them and not the others. How? `n` is in the original question but `i` is not. What hidden quantity does `i` represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can examine and talk through the first case.

The output is supposed to be:

```
Almost
Yes we have arrived
That was annoying
That was annoying
```

If you draw out a number line:

```
<- <0  -         0         -   1  -      2-3-4-5    -   6+       ----->
 Almost|Yes we have arrived|Almost|That was annoying|We just left|
```

Then, we just look at the outputs and start reasoning about it.

Almost occurs on negatives and 1. We can rule out negatives, as there's no way to jump from a negative number to a postive number, as each case does a subtraction. So, that first 'Almost' means n was 1. And that explains the first two lines, but not the last two. So, how do we get 'That was annoying'?

It needs n in the range [2, 5]. And note the case, it makes a recursive call *first*, then prints, 'That was annoying'. So, what starting value of `n` can land in the 'That was annoying' block and call the 'Almost' piece?

The answer is 3. So now we'll just manually walk through the algorithm, assuming n = 3.

When n == 3, it falls into the condition n > 1. The first thing it does is call itself with value n - 2 = **1**. This prints 'Almost', then 'Yes we have arrived' because the block with 'Almost' calls itself with n - 1 = **0**. Now that all of the nested calls are taken care of, we return back to the initial block when n== 3, and print 'That was annoying', but we only print it once. So, 3 isn't right.

If I want 'That was annoying' to be printed again, it should follow that I just need to increment n to 4.

We can do quick check on n = 4. I will land in the "annoying" block, make a call with n - 2 = **2** and land in the "annoying" block again (We need that to print '
That was annoying twice), and make *another* call with n - 2 = **0**. We skipped the 'Almost', so 4 isn't right.

So we look at 5. 5 - 2 = 3, 3 - 2 = 1. Tracing that all the way, should yield the same output.

No code, just a number line and tracking the calls. That can be done with physical notecards, or drawing a recursion stack.

If you look closely at the third output, you should hopefully take note that it's mostly solved already, as the last four lines are the same as the block we just solved.

That's an excellent problem-solving technique; using previously solved problems to break down and solve bigger problems. That's why this assignment is better done without code, and with you coming up with solutions. Other people's solutions ends up being the only solution in your own pool, and you'll struggle more.

Comment: Thank you so much. This explanation really helped me understand how to go about answering the question. I'll continue to use a number line for the following q's.

Comment: I just want to note than some earlier revisions stated that 4 was the correct answer for the first output. That's incorrect and my answer has been updated.